# How to sign PDF with a x.509 signature/certificate

Tags: java, node.js, pdf, digital-signature, x509certificate

***tl;dr:* I'm looking for a CLI tool that can be fed with a x.509 file and an input PDF and out comes a signed PDF. Best scenario for NodeJS**

Hi there. I'm getting a little bit frustrated. I'm looking for a tool which can sign PDF files using the command line. I do use an online service called handy-signatur.at (A service from www.a-trust.at) that generates a x.509 certificate.

I found a [page](http://wiki.cacert.org/PdfSigning) that mentions several tools but it seems that all of them are out of date.

I tried PortableSigner in particular, but that needs Java 6 and I couldn't get it to work on Ubuntu (Server and Desktop edition) 17.04.

**/edit:** I can't get PortableSigner to work because Java 6 and 7 is no longer available and probably not even safe to use.

Is there any commandline tool out there to sign PDFs?

Thank you guys so much!

Comment: I've found this: https://gist.github.com/chrpinedo/a2a2af757e96aec0d6f69d707629a01a if this approach work well for your case, then you can create a Node.js script to do the same, by using pdftk.

Comment: Sadly i don't have a signature image but a x509 certificate

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/commonpdf ?

Comment: Oh that looks good! I have no clue why I didn't find that :D Thank you. If you want, you can write an answer, and i'll accept it as soon as I tried it out!

Comment: Ok wait, this seems to be just a wrapper of PortableSigner, which I don't know how to make it work

Comment: I won't post it as an answer because I don't know yet if this will work. I'm just trying to give you some ideas. And it seems that by using it you won't need to know how PortableSigner works. The method seems to have a method `DigitalSignature` that will handle what is needed, by using PortableSigner under the hood.

Comment: @lumio hint is here https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1849350

Answer (score 9):

Seems [PortableSigner](http://portablesigner.sourceforge.net/) do the work. 
[image]

If you are worried about Java 7 support. Try it with Java 8, probably the digital signature functions still work because nothing important has changed between 7&8

Alternatively, implementing a signature program with Java using libraries like PDFBox or itext is relatively easy. Here you have a full example with pdfbox. Note that it has a `main`

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/signature/CreateSignature.java

usage:

```
java org.apache.pdfbox.examples.signature.CreateSignature 
     <pkcs12_keystore> <password> <pdf_to_sign>
```

Comment: How did you make it work with Java 8? I keep getting errors about having certain modules not installed, even though I did.

Comment: I have not tried it in Java 8.  I just said that digital signature functions between java 7 and 8 have not changed, so PortableSigner probably should work. I also think you can use java 7 safely. I do not know how a future JVM vulnerability,( with low probability of appearing because it is a very proven function )could affect a program launched through command line. Note you are generating a digitally signed file that can be externally verified with just the public key

Comment: @pedrofb wow usage looks so simple. i couldnt understand the pdfbox code when i read it. I had wraped it to a library to sign documents as TS_FilePdfSignUtils.signIfNotSignedBefore(..).  I am using it with JDK17. How come. link: https://github.com/tugalsan/com.tugalsan.api.file.pdf.sign/blob/main/src/main/java/com/tugalsan/api/file/pdf/sign/server/TS_FilePdfSignUtils.java

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own Java scripts here is the reference 
http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/AcrobatDC_js_api_reference.pdf

```
var myEngine = security.getHandler( "Adobe.PPKLite" );
myEngine.login( "password", "/C/Users/username/Desktop/PrivateUser.pfx" );
var myInfo = {password: "password",
 reason: "SaveAs Test",
 mdp: "defaultAndComments"};
this.certifyInvisibleSign({
 oSig:myEngine,
 oInfo:myInfo,
 cDIPath:"/c/temp/sigSign.pdf",
 cLegalAttest: "Certified using JavaScript",
 bUI:false
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I could find, openSSL is the only maintained tool which might support inputting an x.509 file and a PDF in order to generate a signed PDF file.

See [the openSSL man page for x509](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/x509.html).

I also found a PortableSigner2 project, but it also wasn't current.

Answer (score 0):

**PortableSigner** is a tool to digitally sign PDFs with X.509 certificates.

It's a Java app so the installation of a compatible JRE is required (according to the website: 1.6 and 1.7).

You can refer the following link to get the detailed information for the same

http://portablesigner.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, the openssl command can do this but it took me a while to find an example.
Here's the website with a good example:

https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Sign_and_verify_text_files_to_public_keys_via_the_OpenSSL_Command_Line.html

and the commands in case the link doesn't work:

```
To sign:

openssl dgst -sha256 -sign mycert.key -out sign.txt.sha256 sign.txt
```

Where mycert.key is the private key of your x509 certificate.

```
To verify:

openssl dgst -sha256 -verify  mycert.pub -signature sign.txt.sha256 sign.txt
```

Where mycert.pub is the public key of your certificate (NOT the certificate itself).

Comment: It might not be spelled out explicitly but the question is about integrated PDF signatures, not detached signatures.