# how to self signed a pdf with x509 certificat file in node JS framework

Tags: node.js, pdf, npm, npm-install, pdfa

I need to self signed a pdf  with x509 certificat file in node JS framework  but i don't find any useful package in npm to install it

Comment: Do you have the option to create a small microservice to do just this one job, perhaps using another language that does have an easier implementation? Not sure which language to suggest, but it would give you more options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This similar question [How to sign PDF with a x.509 signature/certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44749907/how-to-sign-pdf-with-a-x-509-signature-certificate) has some answers suggesting to use openssl at the command line. This could be done with a microservice and an exec  type command using either node or python for example.

This type of feature is much better done as a microservice, as it allows you to swap out the functionality with another/better service at a later date. As long as you maintain the same API in the microservice, changes will be transparent to your main application

Comment: [link](https://www.example-code.com/nodejs/pdf_signatures.asp)  **I find this useful also**